# Show subtotal excl. tax, add subtotal tax as separate row on Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, checkout

Currently I have all my products set to include tax. Because of rules in my country I would like to have my subtotal without tax, then a line with the amount of tax being paid and then the total with all the taxes (which is already default)

In my review-order.php the line
`<td><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>`
gets called. I would like to subtract the tax percentage (21%) from that so ( / 121 * 100). And then a new line which shows the full tax amount so (total - subtotal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** First, for info, woocommerce templates are made to be [overridden via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Once you have copied the template `checkout/review-order.php` to the "woocommerce" subfolder located in your theme *(as explained on the linked documentation above)*, open/edit this template and replace the following code block (line 58 to 61):

```
<tr class="cart-subtotal">
    <th><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
</tr>
```

By this code bloc:

```
<tr class="cart-subtotal">
    <th><?php printf( __( 'Subtotal %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<small>(excl. tax)<small>' );?></th>
    <td><?php echo wc_price( WC()->cart->get_subtotal() ); ?></td>
</tr>

<tr class="cart-subtotal-tax">
    <th><?php _e( 'Subtotal tax', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php echo wc_price( WC()->cart->get_subtotal_tax() ); ?></td>
</tr>
```

It will give you the subtotal without taxes and on an additional line the subtotal tax amount…

[image]

Comment: i didn't need to try this solution, because the alternate solution presented by @markmoxx achieved the same results just by changing one simple woocommerce  setting -in woocommerce > settings > tax. Seems a bit unnecessary to add a php function for it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Tax options in WC settings and ensure the **Prices entered with tax** option is set to 'Yes, I will enter prices inclusive of tax.'

Change **Display prices during cart and checkout** option from 'Including tax' to 'Excluding tax'.

That should help you achieve what you want without using any code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed to display UK VAT as a separate line item on the checkout and order confirmation and item prices EX VAT - but on the product pages I show prices including VAT. Thank you - nice simple solution without having to add php functions.

Comment: BTW the setting is under woocommerce > settings > tax